# Unable to consume SOAP service

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, soap

I wonder if someone could spare a few minutes to point me in the right direction please?

I'm attempting (and failing) to connect to a SOAP service through ASP.NET, basically I have the URL to the service which should expose the WSDL file, in order to gain access to this document I also need to pass in some credentials which, I believe, discounts adding it as a service request.

Here's what I've tried so far (mainly taken from code samples I've found on the net):

```
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = fireSoapRequest();
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXML = new XmlDocument();

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXML.Save(stream);
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;
        }

    private static HttpWebRequest fireSoapRequest()
    {
        string sdURL = "myNiceURL";
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;



        try {
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sdURL);
            webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:ACTION");
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"uft-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Credentials = GetCredential();
            webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;
        }

        return webRequest;
    }

    public static CredentialCache GetCredential()
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        string sdURL = "myNiceURL";
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(sdURL), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("myUsername", "myPassword"));
        return credentialCache;
    }
```

I believe that the call should return a 'token' which is then used to connect to other SOAP services but I keep receiving the generic 500 server error. Unfortunately the developer who put this service together is currently unavailable so I don't have a great deal of support from that side of the fence. I do know that other parts of the business (using PHP) are successfully connecting so it must be something that I'm doing incorrectly.

The WDSL file is enormous (mostly containing error handling by the looks of it) but here's part (top and bottom) of the file.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:tns="urn:enterprise.soap.com" xmlns:fns="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.com" 
xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.com" targetNamespace="urn:enterprise.soap.com">
<types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace="urn:enterprise.soap.com">
<import namespace="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.com"/>

<!--  Our simple ID Type  -->
<simpleType name="ID">
<restriction base="xsd:string">
<length value="18"/>
<pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>

<complexType name="GetUserInfoResult">
.....
.....
.....
<!--  Soap Service Endpoint  -->
<service name="SforceService">
<documentation>Sforce SOAP API</documentation>
<port binding="tns:SoapBinding" name="Soap">
<soap:address location="https://test.com/services/Soap/c/51.0/0DF9E0000004H4I"/> <!-- Dev2 
sandbox 14Jan2021   -->
</port>
</service>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
C

Comment: Your approach is "close to the metal" so to speak. Have you tried something more high level, like creating a proxy class from the WSDL file using [svcutil and WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client)? That will allow you to call the service just like you call C# methods, and on the long run, if you need to call many operations from that service with its enormous WSDL, it makes it a lot easier than building your messages the way you do now.

Comment: @Bogdan thanks for your response but I don't think that I can add a service reference as I need to pass in credentials. The url is rejected when adding a reference presumably for this reason

Comment: What URL gets rejected? When calling the SOAP service or when getting the WSDL?

Comment: @Bogdan When calling the soap service

Comment: That means you have the WSDL and you can use it to build your proxy. The calls to the web service most likely need some form of authentication. Is there any operation of the service that you can call without authentication? Something simple, as a test.

Comment: @Bogdan Not that I'm aware of hence my trying the 'close to the metal' approach

Comment: In that case, I suggest you feed your WSDL to [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/tools/soapui/) and get some sample requests from it, to figure out what exactly you need to send to the web service